# Unique variable names

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3

I am using [ng2-simple-timer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-simple-timer) in my ionic3 App.

Here is code from repo:

```
counter: number = 0;
timerId: string;
 
ngOnInit() {
    this.timerId = this.st.subscribe('5sec', () => this.callback());
}
 
callback() {
    this.counter++;
}
```

simpletimer will create timer name and tick every 'number' of seconds.

callback will return counter value (0,1,2,3,4,5,6, etc..)

what is my problem?

I want define unique `uniquecounterName: number = 0;` because I have more than one timer.

what will be my results:

- return uniquecounterName(0,1,2,3,4,5,6, etc..)
- return otheruniquecounterName(0,1,2,3,4,5,6, etc..)

in other words callback() function must return pre defined unique variable names like as this.counter

```
callback(var) {
    var++;
}
```

this one will not work because I want use var in my view.
....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible, if you take a look at the "[GitHub: ng2-simple-timer-example](https://github.com/J-Siu/ng2-simple-timer-example/blob/master/app/app.component.ts)", directly from the docs, you'll find how the author deals with multiple timers; I won't quote all the code, you can look at it yourself, but just paste here the way callbacks are handled:

```
timer0callback(): void {
    this.counter0++;
}

timer1callback(): void {
    this.counter1++;
}

timer2callback(): void {
    this.counter2++;
}
```

As you can see, the whole process (new, subscribe, del, unsubscribe) is done for each timer. So the library doesn't support your use case directly.

What you could do is inline the callback function so you have access to the same variables you had when creating it:

```
function sub(name) {
    this.timerId = this.st.subscribe(name, () => {
        // still have access to the name
    });
}
```

Of course this has to be heavily adapted to your purposes, this is as much as I could gather from your question.